# AngularJS - HTML binding not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-routing

In my angular app, there are two pages (list & checkout). In the list page the user could search for an item and the searched item will be displayed and then the user can select the item and continue to checkout. 
                     From the checkout page the user could return back to list page, and at that time all the items in the list page should be same as how it was left before.
For implementing this feature, my code is

on moving from list page to checkout page, all the scope data are stored in a service

```
returnsService.setScopeData($scope);
```

And on returning back from checkout page to list page, this saved data are retrieved from service and assigned to scope variables.

```
var restoreScopeData = returnsService.getScopeData();
if (restoreScopeData) {
        for (var key in restoreScopeData) {
           if (key.charAt(0) != '$') {
                  $scope[key] = restoreScopeData[key];
              }
         }
    }
```

This works fine to an extend, and I can see the list page same as how I left it.
But the problem is, now I'm not able to search for new item in the list page.

When ever a search happens, the items are populated to `$scope.listSearch` and they are displayed in html `{{listSearch}}`.
In the error case also,
I can see the new search data getting assigned to the `$scope.listSearch`, but the HTML binding is not happening.
I tried calling `$scope.$apply()` after the search assigning, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Storing complete scope isn't good idea. You can just store the vars you need. Also, you can use localStorage for this. 
As I understood, making new call is not an option, so you can try use $timeout.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.listSearch = myValue;
});
```

Comment: I think there is some confusion. There are a lot of things in the scope which has to be maintained as such when coming back. After coming back, still the user can search for another item. then definitely a new call is required and the new item details are getting assigned to $scope.listSearch. But the binding is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, you may for localStorage or sessionStorage as suggsted by John.
You may check below link for example

```
 https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1015515/Working-With-Client-Side-Local-Storage
```